# How to compute $i^*:H^*(U^{m+n})\rightarrow H^*(U^m)\bigotimes H^*(U^n)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, classifying-spaces

From $i:U^n\times U^m\rightarrow U^{m+n}$, one has $Bi:BU^n\times BU^m\rightarrow BU^{m+n}.$ The target is to compute $Bi^*.$ By the naturality of spectral sequence of $G\rightarrow EG\rightarrow BG,$ it's equivalent to compute $i^*.$

As $i^*:H^*(U^{m+n})\rightarrow H^*(U^m)\bigotimes H^*(U^n),$ I thought at first that I can use $i_n:U^n\rightarrow U^{m+n},$ $i_m:U^m\rightarrow U^{m+n}$ to derive that $i^*=i_n^*\cdot i_m^*.$ However I find it's strange and I don't think that's correct.

I know we have the following facts.
$$
BU^n=G_n(\mathbb C^\infty),\quad H^*(G_n)=\mathbb Z[c_1,\cdots,c_n],\quad H^*(U_n)=\mathbb Z[a_1,\cdots,a_n].
$$

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: If $T^n$ is a maximal torus of $U(n)$, do you know how to compute the map $H^\ast(BU(n))\rightarrow H^\ast(T^n)$ induced by inclusion?

Comment: You could also try rephrasing your question about computing $Bi^*$ in terms of characteristic classes on vector bundles.